# Python - apply custom function to string columns does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Let's say I have this toy dataset

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'animal': ['lama', 'cow', 'lama', 'beetle', 'lama', 'hippo'],
    'num': range(6)
})
```

and I create two simple custom functions (one for the string column `animal`, one for the numeric column `num`) that I will later use in an `apply` function. Such functions are

```
def fn_num(x):
    if x['num'] >= 5:
        return 1
    elif x['num'] <= 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1

def fn_animal(x):
    if x['animal'].isin(['cow', 'hippo']):
        return 1
    elif x['animal'].str.contains('ee'):
        return 0
    else:
        return -1
```

where the argument `x` should be a pandas `DataFrame` such as the object `df`.

I later use them in an `apply` function (*I know that this is not the most optimized code in terms of efficiency, but I prefer to leave it in this way for the sake of clarity*)

```
df.apply(fn_num, axis=1)

0    0
1    0
2   -1
3   -1
4   -1
5    1
dtype: int64



df.apply(fn_animal, axis=1)

AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'isin'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

The function `fn_num` applied to the numeric column works fine, whereas the function `fn_animal` applied to the string column gives back an error. However, if I write the code outside the custom function, I get no errors with the attribute `isin`:

```
df['animal'].isin(['cow', 'hippo'])

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: animal, dtype: bool



df['animal'].str.contains('ee')

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: animal, dtype: bool
```

My desired output would be:

```
df.apply(fn_animal, axis=1)

0   -1
1    1
2   -1
3    0
4   -1
5    1
dtype: int64
```

I spent quite some type on this issue and I'm sure I'm missing something very silly but I couldn't figure it out. What can I do to make the function `fn_animal` work inside the `apply`?

Comment: at a quick glance - since accessing by row using `x['animal']` gives you a native `str` object... you probably want to change it to: `if x['animal'] in ['cow', 'hippo']` ?

Comment: On a side note and not an answer to how to make it work with `.apply` (but probably a preferred way of doing so) is to use: `df['animal'].replace([r'^(hippo|cow)$', 'ee', '.*'], [1, 0, -1], regex=True)`

Comment: @JonClements Thank you for the side note, it will be important in some other occasions for sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all, you are applying pandas functions on string objects not Dataframe so just use standard `in` operator to check for a string or substring.

Updated code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'animal': ['lama', 'cow', 'lama', 'beetle', 'lama', 'hippo'],
    'num': range(6)
})

def fn_num(x):
    if x['num'] >= 5:
        return 1
    elif x['num'] <= 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1

def fn_animal(x):
    if x['animal'] in (['cow', 'hippo']):
        return 1
    elif 'ee' in x['animal']:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1

print(df.apply(fn_num, axis=1))




print(df.apply(fn_animal, axis=1))
```

Out:

```
0    0
1    0
2   -1
3   -1
4   -1
5    1
dtype: int64
0   -1
1    1
2   -1
3    0
4   -1
5    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the explanation on the error, I'm not very familiar with the error messages!

Comment: I think Serge's answer says clearly about the error, I also mentioned. You are using a function which needs pandas dataframe not a str, that's why.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the apply function, `x` is a Series and no longer a DataFrame. Because of that, `x[y]` is a scalar value, either a numeric (and `fn_num` works fine is `x['num']` is a number) or a plain string.

So in `fn_animal`, `x['animal']` is a plain string and it has no `isin` method: the error is normal.

Comment: I understood what is the error now, thank you for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The objects passed to the function are series objects according the index parameter.
So `x['animal']` is a `str`

Code modification tp `fn_animal()`:

```
def fn_animal(x):
    if x['animal'] in ['cow', 'hippo']:
        return 1
    elif 'ee' in x['animal']:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1
```

Quoting the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply)

> DataFrame.apply(self, func, axis=0, raw=False, result_type=None, args=(), **kwds)[source]¶
>   Apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame.
>
> Objects passed to the function are Series objects whose index is either the DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the DataFrame’s columns (axis=1). By default (result_type=None), the final return type is inferred from the return type of the applied function. Otherwise, it depends on the result_type argument.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!